# Context switching when a thread invokes a system call

Tags: linux, scheduling, system-calls, context-switching

I have a process with multiple threads. If one of my threads invokes a system call like `gettimeofday()`, does the kernel only switch that thread out of context to service the system call, or does it switch the entire process (and all other threads) out of context?

Comment: Linux is 1:1 threaded; see [threading models on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29#Models) for others, such as N:1 where a system call switches out all threads, or M:N where 1≤some≤all may be affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) may involve a context switch (if other tasks are runnable) and switch the processor's state to kernel mode.

But `gettimeofday` (and e.g. `getpid()`) are unusual. with recent kernels they use [VDSO](http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelGlossary#V) to avoid it (and even to avoid the `syscall` or `sysenter` instruction to switch to kernel mode).

Answer (score 1):

To the linux kernel, a thread is a process. So the kernel has no interest in the other threads of your process when one of them makes a syscall.